# In bash shell -E option explanation, what does "any trap inherited by a subshell environment" mean?

Tags: bash, bash-trap

This is from the manual for bash set options (for `set -E`)

> `-E`
>
> If set, any trap on ERR is inherited by shell functions, command substitutions, and commands executed in a subshell environment. The ERR trap is normally not inherited in such cases.

What does "trap on ERR" mean? what does "trap on ERR is inherited by shell functions in a subshell environment"?  Can a shell script proceed even after the trap and the trap is passed to a subshell? Can someone elaborate on this with a simple example, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bash manual on [`trap`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-trap) says:

> `trap [-lp] [arg] [sigspec …]`
>
> …
>
> If a *sigspec* is `ERR`, the command arg is executed whenever a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command), a list, or a compound command returns a non-zero exit status, subject to the following conditions. The `ERR` trap is not executed if the failed command is part of the command list immediately following an `until` or `while` keyword, part of the test following the `if` or `elif` reserved words, part of a command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command’s return status is being inverted using `!`. These are the same conditions obeyed by the `errexit` (`-e`) option.

The material you quote says that `trap '…' ERR` is not normally inherited by a shell function, a command substitution or commands executed in a subshell environment.  However, if you use `set -E`, then the `ERR` trap is inherited.

The sentence means:

- If `set -E` is set, then any trap on ERR is inherited by shell functions.
- If `set -E` is set, then any trap on ERR is inherited by command substitutions.
- If `set -E` is set, then any trap on ERR is inherited by commands executed in a subshell environment.

The 'in a subshell environment' clause does not apply to shell functions or command substitutions.

I can't parse your question "Can a shell script proceed even after the trap and the trap is passed to a subshell?"  A shell script can proceed after a trap — what happens depends on the commands in the `arg` part of the `trap` command.

Here's a shell script that demonstrates `set -E` in action:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
# SO 6485-2814 'trap ERR and set -E'

trap 'echo TRAP ERR >&2' ERR

echo begin-ls
ls /non-existent
echo end-ls

func()
{
    echo begin-func
    ls /non-existent
    echo end-func
}

echo invoke-func
func
echo finish-func

echo begin-substitution
echo $(date): $(ls /non-existent)
echo end-substitution

echo begin-subshell
(ls /non-existent)
echo end-subshell

set -E

echo invoke-func
func
echo finish-func

echo begin-substitution
echo $(date): $(ls /non-existent)
echo end-substitution

echo begin-subshell
(ls /non-existent)
echo end-subshell
```

When run, it produces:

```
begin-ls
ls: /non-existent: No such file or directory
TRAP ERR
end-ls
invoke-func
begin-func
ls: /non-existent: No such file or directory
end-func
finish-func
begin-substitution
ls: /non-existent: No such file or directory
Sun Nov 15 23:16:25 MST 2020:
end-substitution
begin-subshell
ls: /non-existent: No such file or directory
end-subshell
invoke-func
begin-func
ls: /non-existent: No such file or directory
TRAP ERR
end-func
finish-func
begin-substitution
ls: /non-existent: No such file or directory
Sun Nov 15 23:16:25 MST 2020:
end-substitution
begin-subshell
ls: /non-existent: No such file or directory
end-subshell
```

As you can see, the `ERR` trap fires on the failing `ls` command run on its own, but doesn't fail when run in a function or in a subshell or as part of (some) command substitutions.

When the `set -E` option is set, the `ERR` trap fires when the command failed in the function, in the subshell, and in the command substitution.

Curiously, the `ERR` trap does fire in a command substitution like `x=$(ls /non-existent)` but not in the more complex example shown above.  I'm not clear whether that's supposed to happen.
I'm using `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)` — it's possible that later versions of Bash (4.x) do not behave the same.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. In my case, there was a difference : sub-shell inherited the trap before setting -E. Anyway, now I can understand it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A minor edit in the script shared by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler). The edit is to contain the `ls` executed directly (without command substitution, function call, and subshell) with the `-E` option set. Also, attached is the output as from execution on `bash 5.0.17(1)-release`. In this output, it can be seen that the `TRAP` fires for all four cases, namely, execution of command directly from the script, in a function, in a subshell, and in a command substitution. Whereas in the output shared by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler), the `TRAP` does not seem to be fired for command substitution and subshell even with the `-E` flag set.

The script:

```
#! /bin/bash
# SO 6485-2814 'trap ERR and set -E'
trap 'echo TRAP ERR >&2' ERR

echo begin-ls
ls /non-existent
echo end-ls
echo ""

func()
{
    echo begin-func
    ls /non-existent
    echo end-func
}

echo invoke-func
func
echo finish-func
echo ""

echo begin-substitution
echo $(date): $(ls /non-existent)
echo end-substitution
echo ""

echo begin-subshell
(ls /non-existent)
echo end-subshell

echo "************ Set -E ****************"
set -E
echo begin-ls
ls /non-existent
echo end-ls
echo ""

echo invoke-func
func
echo finish-func
echo ""

echo begin-substitution
echo $(date): $(ls /non-existent)
echo end-substitution
echo ""

echo begin-subshell
(ls /non-existent)
echo end-subshell
```

Output:
begin-ls
ls: cannot access '/non-existent': No such file or directory
TRAP ERR
end-ls

```
invoke-func
begin-func
ls: cannot access '/non-existent': No such file or directory
end-func
finish-func

begin-substitution
ls: cannot access '/non-existent': No such file or directory
Monday 31 January 2022 01:45:06 PM IST:
end-substitution

begin-subshell
ls: cannot access '/non-existent': No such file or directory
TRAP ERR
end-subshell
************ Set -E ****************
begin-ls
ls: cannot access '/non-existent': No such file or directory
TRAP ERR
end-ls

invoke-func
begin-func
ls: cannot access '/non-existent': No such file or directory
TRAP ERR
end-func
finish-func

begin-substitution
ls: cannot access '/non-existent': No such file or directory
TRAP ERR
Monday 31 January 2022 01:45:06 PM IST:
end-substitution

begin-subshell
ls: cannot access '/non-existent': No such file or directory
TRAP ERR
end-subshell
```